# Vocations and what people are famous for

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

The lead section on Wikipedia biographies tend to contain:

- Their birth name
- Their date of birth (in brackets)
- Their vocation(s), and/or the thing(s) they are famous for

I'm aware this is called the lead section, but I'm specifically interested in the last bit.

**Is there a name for a sentence that describes a person's vocation(s) and/or the thing(s) they are famous for?**

Comment: *Defining characteristic?* Not a sentence name but an attribute descriptor.

Comment: @bib Apologies, I should've mentioned I'm aiming for a single word where possible.

Comment: Closest I can think of is the phrase *claim to fame*. It doesn't appear to be hyphenated in any standard dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

*Raison d'être* is frequently used to describe the reason a thing or a persons is relevant.  French, meaning "reason for existance".